# Save Button in Preferences does not visibly update

Tags: bug, preferences

In the preferences screen, **the save button appears grayed until changes are made**.

[image: screenshot1]

**Clicking the dropdown menu** in the Inbox emails section **automatically selects the associated checkbox**.  However, this does not register as a change, and the **button continues to be grayed**.

[image: screenshot2]

Only after clicking the checkbox to once more disable it, and thus resetting it to its original state, does the settings button finally appear enabled.

Comment: I can confirm that it selects the checkbox upon opening the drop-down menu, but it doesn't enable the button until you actually *select* something in the drop-down (being something other than what was already selected).

Comment: @TLama Sorry, I should mention, this is in Firefox 25.0.1

Comment: @animuson The fact that the checkbox has changed is substantial reason for the save button to become enabled.  What if I want the default of "daily," and just close the dropdown again instead of selecting it?  Do I have to realize my "mistake," then open the menu again and select it for real?

Comment: No, sorry. My mistake. I can see the same issue. That check box is checked immediately when that combo box is dropped down. As a "fix" I would just disable that combo box when that check box is unchecked.

Comment: Reproduced on Opera 17.0.1241.53, win64.

Comment: @TLama A better fix would be to only select the checkbox once something from the dropdown menu is chosen, rather than increasing the number of steps in the process. (It's pretty nice I get to enable this by picking from the dropdown)

Comment: @Jonathan, that check box is there for you to check, not for that combo box. If I'd like a single step, I would rather prefer to remove that check box and add a "Never" item to that combo box.

Comment: @TLama  Would you choose an inbox delivery frequency if you weren't choosing to receive inbox messages though? It makes sense to have the dropdown box check it. (That said, no checkbox and a 'never' option makes sense too)

Comment: @Jonathan, I wouldn't even try it because that check box is unchecked and I'm feeling that option as unavailable. But it's just a matter of taste. I'm not changing these settings so often that I would need one or the other way. Southpaw Hare, I've deleted my initial comment to not mislead anyone else.